# Como passar o valor de uma variavel através da função form_open codeigniter?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

Boa noite Usando o codeigniter como faço para passar o valor de uma variável através da função form_open()? pois aqui tenho que informar o controlador e o método que será responsável pela execução do formulário, sei que sem o codeigniter é possível passar as variáveis por parâmetro através do form action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar o método diretamente:

```
echo form_open('email/send');
```

O Ci vai montar a tag

`<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http://example.com/index.php/email/send">`

Você também pode passar os atributos em forma de Array:

```
    $attributes = array('class' => 'email', 'id' => 'myform');
    echo form_open('email/send', $attributes);
```

Ou diretamente como string:

```
echo form_open('email/send', 'class="email" id="myform"');
```

As duas maneiras vão gerar a tag:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http://example.com/index.php/email/send" class="email" id="myform">
```

Comment: Obrigada deu certo aqui valeu pelas dicas, não tinha encontrado na internet uma definição melhor que a sua.